# Windows Phone App navigation issues

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8

I have an application in which within one page i hit a web service and take response and save it into database and shown data into the list.
next i have a refresh button to refresh and load the list again from web service. while refreshing if i click the device back button, then i am not redirected to the desired page instead it closes the application.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
   {
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
      {
       NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MyApp/MSample.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
      });     
   }
```

Comment: you are missing e.cancel = true

Comment: i cannot need back button to stop its function but instead to go back to the specified url that is MSample.xaml. instead i am throw out of application

Answer (score 0):

pressing the back button takes you to the previous page, if it exists, otherwise you leave the app. As far as I know, it's not recommended to change this behavior as it would be confusing for users

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i have a previous page that is MSample.xaml it should navigate to this url defaultly but instead its going out of application.

Comment: are you sure you should have a page in the history? do you get to the current page where you push the back button from the MSample.xaml? Maybe you have an exception which you don't catch - this exiting (crash) the app?